# schedule task with spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler

I want to run the following method every specific time in spring mvc project it works fine and print  first output
but it doesn't  access the database  so it doesn't display list

the method

```
 public class ScheduleService {

@Autowired
private UserDetailService userDetailService;

public void performService() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("first output");
    List<UserDetail> list=userDetailService.getAll();
    System.out.println(list);

}
```

config file

```
 <!-- Spring's scheduling support -->
<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="taskScheduler">
   <task:scheduled ref="ScheduleService" method="performService" fixed-delay="2000"/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>

<!-- The bean that does the actual work -->
<bean id="ScheduleService" class="com.ctbllc.ctb.scheduling.ScheduleService" />

<!-- Defines a ThreadPoolTaskScheduler instance with configurable pool size. -->
<task:scheduler id="taskScheduler" pool-size="1"/>
```

Comment: so this is not a quesiton about scheduled tasks then, whats the log say. How does the user service access db

Comment: I tried to run it in a controller and works fine but when put it in  this ScheduleService class with @service annotation doesn't print list

Answer (score 1):

try this (and remove bean definition from xml file):

```
@Component
public class ScheduleService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailService userDetailService;

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 2000L) // in msec
    public void performService() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("first output");
        List<UserDetail> list=userDetailService.getAll();
        System.out.println(list);

    }

}
```

Comment: It doesn't work,the method just print (first output)

Comment: Then your `getAll()` method is blocking somehow. comment out that line and try running. Further debug your service method in this case its `getAll()`.

Comment: getAll method run fine when use it in controller but here not work

Answer (score 0):

Write an integration test for that specific service and see if the service method calls returns anything at all. Manually testing always leads to such problems. Start with tests and debug if necessary.